# Xquery 1.0 - average over elements with subelements

Tags: xpath, xquery

So I have an XML file that has elements with numbers in them, and also some sub elements with numbers in them. Something like:

```
<data>
    <points>
        <score>80</score>
        <score>90</score>
        <score>10</score>
        <score>13</score> 
    </points>
    <favor>50</favor>
    <ranked>
        <rank>50</rank>
        <rank>10</rank>
    </ranked>
</data>
```

I want to compute the average across all these elements that have numbers including sub elements. So, I want a query that could produce:

(80+90+10+13+50+50+10) / 7 = 43.285714286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expression `//*[not(*)]` to select *leaf elements* (element that doesn't have child element), anywhere in the XML document :

```
let $elements := //*[not(*)]
return sum($elements) div count($elements)
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/f15851b84a1fe0541795e572ca564bb8)</kbd>**